# Detect right click delete/cut/copy tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, tinymce

How can I detect right click delete on tinymce ? I detected the paste event by the onPaste event, but I am stuck on the cut delete and copy. I know that there is the event onContextMenu but there doesn't seem to be a function or variable that holds the menu items.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "right click delete" you mean selecting delete from the dropdown browser right click menu. Problem here is that there is no adequate event being fired in the tinymce iframe. The only thing which comes to my mind is the event onNodeChange. This should get fired, but this one gets fired on several kind of other tasks too.
Another (not easy) option is to develop an own BrowserAddOn which can listen for a browser intern event and then do its magic.

Comment: yes that's what I meant. Yeah cause I noticed that there is no event for it. Maybe I will disable it from the context menu.. its not that important anyway. But what about the right click cut ? Do you know of an event for it ? Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: No, there are no events getting fired if you choose anything from a right click menu, except for events that will get fired indirectly by it (like onNodeChange). It is possible to create an own right click menu (have a look at the tinymce plugin contextmenu to find out how that works) where you can list some of the operations available from the native browser menu.

Comment: I am unable to fire 2 events. KeyUp and paste when they are both written one after the other.